# Visual Studio 2019, .NET 5 missing after installing SDK

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I just installed the .NET 5 SDK, and created a new C# library.
The .NET 5 is missing from available frameworks. I've tried both standard, core and .net version of the library template.

[image]

As this was newly released, I can't find any hints on what I am missing with the good 'ole google search.

Comment: Which VS version?

Comment: I was using vs 2019 version 16.7.7, and it seems version 16.8 or later is required. Updating now, so it will probably resolve the issue

Comment: Yes, there it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using VS2019 version 16.7.7, but 16.8 or later is required for .NET 5.0.

My bad. Should've checked the requirements before creating this question. Sorry